# jlink on Windows fails w "Error: Duplicate entry!"

Tags: java, windows, jlink, openjdk-11

I am trying to build a JRE on Windows 10 with OpenJDK 11. I ALWAYS get a error message, so maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Here is a simple invocation of jlink:

```
C:\Users\en>"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.9.11-hotspot\bin\jlink.exe" --add-modules java.se --bind-services --output X:\jdk11
Error: Duplicate entry!
java.lang.AssertionError: Duplicate entry!
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.builder.DefaultImageBuilder.lambda$storeFiles$1(DefaultImageBuilder.java:176)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.builder.DefaultImageBuilder.storeFiles(DefaultImageBuilder.java:171)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.ImagePluginStack.storeFiles(ImagePluginStack.java:498)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.ImageFileCreator.writeImage(ImageFileCreator.java:166)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.ImageFileCreator.create(ImageFileCreator.java:100)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask$ImageHelper.retrieve(JlinkTask.java:851)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.ImagePluginStack.operate(ImagePluginStack.java:206)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.createImage(JlinkTask.java:408)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.run(JlinkTask.java:272)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Main.run(Main.java:54)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: X:\jdk11\conf\security
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:87)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:509)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:689)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:796)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:742)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.builder.DefaultImageBuilder.writeEntry(DefaultImageBuilder.java:440)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.builder.DefaultImageBuilder.accept(DefaultImageBuilder.java:411)
        at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.builder.DefaultImageBuilder.lambda$storeFiles$1(DefaultImageBuilder.java:173)
        ... 19 more
```

I get the same result with JDK 14 on Windows. However, the same command works on Linux and produces a JRE image.

Comment: jlink should always be given an empty image directory.

Comment: Actually jlink complains if the directory even exists. I remove the output directory before running jlink.

Comment: What happens if you use `java.base` instead of java.se?

Comment: Same error, but different file. I noticed that no two runs fail at the same file.

Comment: It turned out to be some nasty network issue between my Linux host and the Windows  guest. The X drive was on a network share mapped from the host. The same command worked fine when the output was directed to drive C. The strange thing is that copying files from either side of the share works (no checksum errors).

Comment: Interesting.  Feel free to post an answer to your own question and accept it.  I imagine this will be useful information for others.